# How can I get the URL given in "-Denvironment=yourUrlHere"

Tags: serenity-bdd, serenity

How can I get webdriver.base.url from a method in java preferrably before executing @Test method ? Tests are started like this "mvn clean verify -Denvironment= preproduction" from a Jenkins pipeline

tried until now: getBaseUrl() but it is private inside PageObject class

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```java
import net.serenitybdd.core.steps.UIInteractions;


public class NavigateActions extends UIInteractions {

    EnvironmentVariables env;

    public String getBaseUrl() {
        return EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(env).getProperty("webdriver.base.url");   
    }
}
```